# How to add video to html page ?

Tags: html, video-streaming, html5-video

I have a 15mb video file I want to be played on my website.

I wonder if I use video html5 tag will this file be downloaded before playing or will it stream?

What is the best way to serve videos nowadays - without putting it into youtube or installing own media server like wowza?

Comment: HTML5 video tag will stream the video file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
<source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
<source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Here is a quick help -> http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp
And Yes html5 player will work for you